# Using return data from an async function, in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm doing a little data analysis from chess.com data

I have this code

```
const getUsernames = async function() {
  let response = await chessAPI.getCountryPlayers('RE')
  names = [...response.body.players]
  //console.log(names)
  return names
}

const grabPlayerScores = async function() {
  let players = getUsernames()
  // let playerStats = [];
  for (i = 0; i = players.length; i++) {
    let data = await chessAPI.getPlayerStats(i)
    console.log(data)
  }
}

grabPlayerScores();
```

I can't get the other function to await the return of the first. I know I should use promises or structure my other function differently but I'm still getting the hang of these types of functions.

Comment: You need `let players = await getUsernames()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice, you should make sure all of your functions return a value. Use `const` for variables that will not change, and `let` for variables that you absolutely will change. Watch out for `name = ...` where you didn't write `const` *or* `let`, as this makes `names` into a global -

```js
const getUsernames = async function() {
  const response = await chessAPI.getCountryPlayers('RE')
  return response.body.players // <- probably no need to copy
}
```

```js
const grabPlayerScores = async function() {
  const players = await getUsernames()
  return Promise.all(players.map(p => chessAPI.getPlayerStats(p)))
}
```

Now `grabPlayerScores` will be a promise containing an array of all player scores -

```js
grabPlayerScores().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

```js
[ ..., ... ,... ]
```

Maybe you want the player data combined with the score data in the final output?

```js
const grabPlayerScores = async function() {
  const players = await getUsernames()
  return Promise.all(players.map(async p => ({
    player: p,
    scores: await chessAPI.getPlayerStats(p)
  })))
}
```

```js
grabPlayerScores().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

```js
[ { player: "alice", scores: ... },
  { player: "brenda", scores: ... },
  { player: "catherine", scores: ... } ]
```

---

Another good practice is to make your functions take parameters. This makes them more reusable in other areas of your program -

```js
const getUsernames = async function(countryCode) {
  const response = await chessAPI.getCountryPlayers(countryCode)
  return response.body.players
}

const grabPlayerScores = async function(countryCode) {
  const players = await getUsernames(countryCode)
  return Promise.all(players.map(async p => ({
    player: p,
    scores: await chessAPI.getPlayerStats(p)
  })))
}
```

Now you pass `"RE"` as an argument to your function, allowing you to easily reuse this function for other countries -

```js
grabPlayerScores("RE").then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Wow thats super helpful! 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another `await` in your `grabPlayerScores` function to wait for `getUsernames` to finish.

```js
const grabPlayerScores = async function() {
  // Add an 'await' here
  let players = await getUsernames();

  for(let i = 0; i = players.length; i++) {
    let data = await chessAPI.getPlayerStats(i)
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed bit in your code,

```
const grabPlayerScores = async function () {
  let players = await getUsernames();
  for (i = 0; i = players.length; i++) {
    let data = await chessAPI.getPlayerStats(players[i]);
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```